Why is writing a file using Splice slower when done asynchronously?
I'm trying to make a program to write files efficiently from data received in a socket.
My approach here is to use the splice Linux syscall, so I made a quick program to do this, and then I tried making the task asynchrnous. Here's what I do:
Synchronous:

Splice from socket into a pipe
Splice from pipe into a file

Asynchronous:

Thread 1: continuously splice from socket to pipe
Thread 2: continuously splice from pipe to file.

I tried setting thread affinity, with no noticeable difference (Because both threads use system time and not CPU time maybe?)
How can this be slower, while also using 2 times more resources?
Also, can the asynchronous approach be faster than the synchronous one if doing optimizations?

You'll need to show us the code and the numbers you're seeing, for starters...

@AKX I think that's unnecessary, as this would just make the question language-specific, and the idea is pretty simple.

How do you know there isn't some bug in the code you've written that just so happens to make it slow in this instance?

Why are you using pipes at all? Look into sendfile().

@AKX because my code is very simple

@Shawn sendfile only works from file to socket and not the opposite
